# Конвертация символов \xd0\x90\xd0\xb4

Tags: python

Имеется строка `\xd0\x90\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81`, как ее преобразить в нормальный вид с помощью python?

Comment: Зависит от того, как эта строчка получилась. Приведите код, который даёт эту строчку

Comment: @jfs и вы тоже почему-то попытались угадать ответ, хотя для вас это не типично

Comment: @andreymal: по ссылке уже есть ответ. Если автору, что-то другое нужно, пусть отредактирует вопрос.

Comment: @jfs должно быть наоборот: сперва редактируется вопрос, а потом решается, есть ответ или нет

Comment: @andreymal: в том виде как сейчас, ответ присутствует по ссылке (`decode('utf-8')`).

Comment: @jfs в текущем в виде в вопросе нигде не сказано, что речь о байтовой строке. `print(u'\\xd0\\x90') → \xd0\x90`

Comment: @andreymal: то есть вы считаете, что вопрос слишком расплывчатый, чтобы на него определённый ответ дать? И автору следует уточнить вопрос?

Comment: @jfs да . . . .

Answer (score 2):

```
print(b"\xd0\x90\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81".decode('UTF-8')) # Адрес
```